# Extract last tuple

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a text file of mysqldump commands. It looks something like this...

```
INSERT INTO `agent_new` VALUES ('1', 'abc'), ('2', 'xyz'), ('3', 'pqr');
```

I need the last entry from the list of tuples. I also need the table name. So the expected output will be

```
INSERT INTO `agent_new` VALUES ('3', 'pqr');
```

The last row will always have a semi colon at the end for e.g. 'pqr');

I need to extract the last row to compare with the actual database. I can do "tail" but I will like to know if there is any better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed 's/(.*(/(/' file
```

Results:

```
INSERT INTO `agent_new` VALUES ('3', 'pqr');
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed "s/('[^']*', '[^']*'), //g" file
```

or:

```
sed 's/('\''.*'\''),//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

using delimiters you should be able to pick through the stream and take what you want. 
I havent looked at the syntax in a while so I dont want to write some code that isn't 100% correct, but i recommend googling some examples involving delimiters !

Sorry I couldn't be more help (n)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/\(.*\), //' filename
```

This should do what you want.